# GWT Polymer on Google App Engine (JDK 7)

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt-polymer

I have a **GWT** based application deployed on **GAE** for Java. I'm planning to try out **GWT Polymer**. **GAE** doesn't support JDK 8 as of now.

Does **GWT Polymer** require **JDK 8** or would it work with **JDK 7**?

I cannot find this information on the project page.

Answer (score 0):

As things are very fluid at this time, I suggest building the sample todolist app, enhancing it with your other dependencies, and confirming it working for your configuration.

FWIW, I just performed this exercise and ran into multiple frustrations forcing me to upgrade gwt to 2.8 SNAPSHOT which then requires Java 8. I then ran into a blocker with google-gin that I've posted to the google groups.

Comment: Thanks @Stevko. GWT Polymer requires GWT-2.8.0-SNAPSHOT (it's stated on their project page on GitHub) and that in turn requires Java 8. So, in essence, I cannot use GWT Polymer with GAE (which doesn't support Java 8) at the moment. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using: GWT 2.8.0 beta 1,  jdk level 1.7 (for GAE ),
vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.2.1.0.jar.
All works fine.